# High performance implement of atomic minimal operation

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, intel, intel-mic, intel-parallel-studio

There is no atomic minimal operation in OpenMP, also no intrinsic in Intel MIC's instruction set.

`#pragmma omp critial` is very insufficient in the performance.

I want to know if there is a high performance implement of `atomic minimal` for Intel MIC.

Comment: Don't you know `#pragma omp atomic`?

Comment: `#pragma omp atomic` only applies to `++`, `--`, `op=`, etc, which usually can be compiled into a single processor opcode, such as increments, decrements, xors. @Kyle_the_hacker

Comment: Are you looking for min of integers, or one of the floating point types? In C or Fortran?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [OpenMP 4.0 Specifications](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) (Section 2.12.6), **there is** a lot of fast atomic minimal operations you can do by using the `#pragma omp atomic` construct in place of `#pragma omp critical` (and thereby avoid the huge overhead of its lock).

---

### Overview of the possibilities with the `#pragma omp atomic` construct

Let `x` be your thread-shared variable:

- With `#pragma omp atomic read` you can atomically let your shared variable `x` be read:

  ```
  v = x;
  ```
- With `#pragma omp atomic write` you can atomically assign a new value to your shared variable `x`; the new value expression (`expr`) has to be `x`-independant:

  ```
  x = expr;
  ```
- With `#pragma omp atomic update` you can atomically update your shared variable `x`; in fact you can only assign a new value as a binary operation (`binop`) between an `x`-independant expression and `x`:

  ```
  x++;
  x--;
  ++x;
  --x;
  x binop= expr;
  x = x binop expr;
  x = expr binop x;
  ```
- With `#pragma omp atomic capture` you can atomically let your shared variable `x` be read and updated (in the order you want); in fact `capture` is a combination of the `read` and `update` construct:

  - You have short forms for `update` and then `read`:

    ```
    v = ++x;
    v = --x;
    v = x binop= expr;
    v = x = x binop expr;
    v = x = expr binop x;
    ```
  - And their *structured-block* analogs:

    ```
    {--x; v = x;}
    {x--; v = x;}
    {++x; v = x;}
    {x++; v = x;}
    {x binop= expr; v = x;}
    {x = x binop expr; v = x;}
    {x = expr binop x; v = x;}
    ```
  - And you have a few short forms for `read` and then `update`:

    ```
    v = x++;
    v = x--;
    ```
  - And again their *structured-block* analogs:

    ```
    {v = x; x++;}
    {v = x; ++x;}
    {v = x; x--;}
    {v = x; --x;}
    ```
  - And finally you have additional `read` then `update`, which only exists in *structured-block* forms :

    ```
    {v = x; x binop= expr;}
    {v = x; x = x binop expr;}
    {v = x; x = expr binop x;}
    {v = x; x = expr;}
    ```

In the preceding expressions:

- `x` and `v` are both [l-value expressions](http://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/l-values-r-values-expressions-and-types) with scalar type;
- `expr` is an expression with scalar type;
- `binop` is one of `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `<<` or `>>`;
- `binop`, `binop=`, `++` and `--` are not overloaded operators.